# Strange behaviour of checkboxes in datagrid with flags

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, flags

I noticed strange behaviour in my datagrid where I show object with flags property.

When I click checkbox in row1,column1 and checkbox in row2,column2:
checkbox in row2,column1 is changed too.

It's like first row remember changes and apply it to next row too :/
Sorry for mistakes in English.

Codes:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridFlags.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridFlags"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:FlagConverter x:Key="FlagsConverter" />
    <local:EnumConverter x:Key="EnumsConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
<DataGrid Margin="20" x:Name="list" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="File type" Binding="{Binding FileType, Converter={StaticResource EnumsConverter}}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="Read">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="Read" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Operations, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource FlagsConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:AllowedOperations.Read}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="Edit">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="Edit" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Operations, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource FlagsConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:AllowedOperations.Edit}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox  Content="Delete" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Operations, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource FlagsConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:AllowedOperations.Delete}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Summary" Binding="{Binding Operations}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Permit.cs

```
public class Permit : BindableBase
{
    private AllowedOperations _operations;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FileType FileType { get; set; }
    public AllowedOperations Operations
    {
        get { return _operations; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _operations, value); }
    }

}
```

FlagConverter.cs

```
class FlagConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private int targetValue;

    public FlagConverter()
    {
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int mask = (int)parameter;
        this.targetValue = (int)value;

        return ((mask & this.targetValue) != 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        this.targetValue ^= (int)parameter;
        return Enum.Parse(targetType, this.targetValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

AllowedOperations.cs

```
  [Flags]
public enum AllowedOperations
{
    Read = 1,
    Edit = 2,
    Delete = 4
}
```

Github: https://github.com/kaczanpiotr/DataGridFlags

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RqeN.png)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the issue, and paste the code and XAML as text into your question. We vigorously discourage links to off-site code repositories, and you can't seriously expect people to dig through all of that code hoping to guess at exactly where the issue is. Help us to help you. Do your share of the work.

Comment: added some codes

Comment: targetValue should not be a field. Make it a local variable in the Convert() method. I haven’t tested the code yet but that is obviously wrong and should be fixed.

Comment: So what to do in ConvertBack method? There is targetValue too

Comment: Please provide definition of `AllowedOperations`. I shouldn't have to keep asking for more information when you already know what information you should provide.

Comment: Added more code and screeon from app

Comment: I was right, the problem is that targetValue is a field. You have **one (1)** instance of `FlagConverter` in your application. This is a problem, because when `ConvertBack` is called for any given binding, `targetValue` is a value that was last set by some other binding.

Comment: So what I have to do? Create three converters or somehow null converter instance?

Comment: You need at least one converter per row, not just three of them. All three columns in a given row are bound to the same value, so it's not a huge deal if you share the same converter for the three columns on the same row. Anyway see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for help, @Ed Plunkett.
Thanks to you I found much simple solution. I only added x:Shared property to converter

```
<local:FlagConverter x:Key="FlagsConverter" x:Shared="False" />
```

For now it's working, i think :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `targetValue` is a field. If you are sharing a static instance of a converter among bindings to different properties of different objects, `Convert()` and `ConvertBack()` must be [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Yours aren't.

Instead, you have one `targetValue` shared among all the bindings in your DataGrid. `Convert()` sets `targetValue`, then the next call to `ConvertBack()` uses that value of `targetValue` -- but now it's a different row.

I've rewritten your converter as a `MarkupExtension`, so you can conveniently create a new instance of it for each cell in each row. Don't sweat the cost of creating a a pile of these things. Compared to the cost of everything else we're creating for each cell, it's of no consequence.

I've also made the flag mask a constructor parameter. You could simplify usage of this thing by making the constructor parameter of type `AllowedOperations`, but you wrote a converter that works with any flag enum type, and I thought that flexibility was worth keeping.

```
public class FlagConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    private int _mask;
    private int _targetValue;

    public FlagConverter(object enumValue)
    {
        _mask = (int)enumValue;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        _targetValue = (int)value;

        return ((_mask & _targetValue) != 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        _targetValue ^= _mask;
        return Enum.Parse(targetType, _targetValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

And here's how you'll use it now. It's no longer being created in Window.Resources.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="Read">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox 
                Content="Read" 
                IsChecked="{Binding Operations, Converter={local:FlagConverter {x:Static local:AllowedOperations.Read}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100" Header="Edit">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox 
                Content="Edit" 
                IsChecked="{Binding Operations, Converter={local:FlagConverter {x:Static local:AllowedOperations.Edit}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox  
                Content="Delete" 
                IsChecked="{Binding Operations, Converter={local:FlagConverter {x:Static local:AllowedOperations.Delete}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I don't particularly like this implementation, because in WPF there is a general assumption that `Convert()` and `ConvertBack()` are pure functions, and **it violates the assumption**. Don't discount the tendency to trust that assumption: You got here by casually trusting it yourself.

However, ConvertBack needs two inputs, and I don't know of another way to get it the second one.